# Using derived type for recursive tree method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class `BinaryTree<T>` that looks like this:

```
 class BinaryTree<T> 
        where T : IComparable
    {
        protected BinaryTree<T>? _left;
        protected BinaryTree<T>? _right;
        protected BinaryTree<T>? _root;
        protected T _value;

        public T Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }

        public BinaryTree<T>? Left
        {
            get { return _left; }
            set { _left = value; }
        }

        public BinaryTree<T>? Right
        {
            get { return _right; }
            set { _right = value; }
        }

        public BinaryTree<T>? Root
        {
            get { return _root; }
            set { _root = value; }
        }
      
        public BinaryTree() { }

        public BinaryTree(T value, BinaryTree<T>? left = null, BinaryTree<T>? right = null, BinaryTree<T>? root = null)
        { ... }
        public List<T> PreOrder()
        { ... }

        public List<T> InOrder()
        { ... }

        public List<T> PostOrder()
        { ... }
    }
```

And a dervied class `BinarySearchTree` that implements the `Search` method:

```
class BinarySearchTree : BinaryTree<int>
    {
        public BinarySearchTree() : base() { } 

        public Boolean Search(int value)
        {
            if (Value.CompareTo(value) == 0) return true;
            if ((Left is not null) && (Value.CompareTo(value) > 0)) { return Left.Search(value); }
            else if ((Right is not null) && (Value.CompareTo(value) > 0)) { return Right.Search(value); }
            else { return false; }
        }
    }
```

`Left.Search` (and analagously `Right`) won't work because `Left` isn't of type `BinarySearchTree`, but rather `BinaryTree<int>`. I know that you can solve this by overriding `_left`, `_right`, `Left` and `Right` in `BinaryTree`, but that seems redundant since the new code isn't doing anything functionally different. I also know that we could just move `Search` to `BinaryTree` in this case, but that isn't the point; in the case of more complicated methods that I only want to have in a derived class it seems like this kind of functionality should be available somewhere.

My initial idea was to try to set the type of `_left` and `_right` in the base class to whatever the derived class would be. It doesn't seem like that's possible though; I can get the type as string using `GetType()` but I can't define a property with that type.

Comment: You can create an extension method instead of a derived class. In this way it'll apply to the root and all the children

Comment: How about making `BinaryTree<T>` `abstract` and adding an abstract method `public abstract Boolean Search(T value);` in it?

Comment: @Magnus I'd like to keep the method in the derived class. In this case moving it to `BinaryTree` makes sense, but not for all such methods. It's the functionality I'm interested in, not solving this particular problem; this is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should probably use composition instead of inheritance, i.e. make `BinaryTree<int>` a field or property of `BinarySearchTree`. Composition tend to make code easier to use and reason about since you don't have to worry about complex inheritance hierarchies.

```
class BinarySearchTree 
{
    private BinaryTree<int> root;
}
```

You can then make your search method take a node as input parameter, commonly using an private method for recursion, and a public method that uses the root:

```
class BinarySearchTree 
{
    private BinaryTree<int> root;
    public Boolean Search(int value) => Search(root, value);
    private Boolean Search(BinaryTree<int> node, int value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, there are some things other things I would consider fixing.

Recursive techniques have some problems. If the tree is poorly balanced it can lean to stack overflows. I would recommend thinking about using a iterative technique instead. That should be fairly simple for a binary search method.

Use a `IComparer<T>` parameter instead of `IComparable` restriction, and an overload that uses `Comparer<T>.Default` if the user does not specifically give you one. This is a good compromise between flexibility and ease of use, and is the pattern most of the framework uses.

Use a functional approach rather than a class based approach. That tend to make the code easier to reuse, since you are not tied to a specific tree type. A signature might for example look something like this:

```
public static bool BinarySearch<T>(T current, T value, Func<T, (T? Left, T? Right)> selector, IComparer<T> comparer)
```

If you are handling large trees of primitive types, it is often more useful to describe the tree using an array. Objects have some overhead, and if you have a very large amount of ints, that overhead will dominiate. Sometimes, using arrays and indexes to that array can be a better solution when dealing with lots of data, a typical example would be something like a heap.